# C# Typeresticted delegate with Template

Tags: c#, templates, delegates, limit

The .net EventHandler is limited to Templates that inherits from EventArgs. How is that done? The implementation (Got to refference in vs) shows the following code:

```
[Serializable]
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e);
```

But i think TEventArgs is just a name. How can I write a typed delegate that is limites to anything that inherits from MyClass?

Comment: I can see the solution in 2 seconds if I look on the code from Jon Skeet. I used both answers and don't want to miss the link to the documentation, but I can only mark one answer as correct.

Comment: To add the link isn't a fault ;) But write the obvious part down, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TEventArgs` is a *generic type parameter* - but it has a constraint. The actual signature is:

```
[Serializable]
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e)
    where TEventArgs : EventArgs
```

The "`where TEventArgs : EventArgs`" bit is the type constraint which means you can only supply a *type argument* for `TEventArgs` which is `EventArgs` or a derived class.

Basically it's just "normal" C# generics, just applied to a delegate declaration.